# Extract Data from A URL with Python

Tags: python, parsing, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to extract data from a website using Python and BeautifulSoup. The data I need is in a table.

I know how to select a table on a page by using `soup.select('table.class_name')`. However, there are multiple tables on this page with same class name. What is the code to select the table by the id instead.

The html is

```
<table class="stats_table sortable min_width now_sortable sticky_table eq1 re1 le1 is_sorted" id="matchlogs_for" data-cols-to-freeze=",1">
```

The code I tried

```
team1_link = team_links[0]
data = urlopen(team1_link,)
soup = BeautifulSoup(data, 'html.parser')
table = soup.select('table.stats_table')
```

There are multiple tables with the class name "stats_table" so I was getting the wrong data back

Comment: `soup.select('table#matchlogs_for')` will select by ID.

Comment: `soup.find(id="matchlogs_for")`

Comment: Right.  The rule in making CSS selectors is that dot  `.` specifies a CSS class, and pound `#` specifies a tag id.

Comment: Thank you. Thats really helpful to know. I'll make sure I remember that @TimRoberts